# php5.6 variable is not visible for code

Tags: php, mysql

I have simple msql based glossary - which stop working after upgrade from php5.4 to php 5.6.28

In form i send a variable to address like `page.php?word=xxx`

in page.php it should get $word from table.word with table.definition

Connection with database is working.

Error log looks

```
array(1) { ["word"]=string(5) "xxx" } bool(true)
```

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

my code is

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$configfile = "config.php";
require $configfile;
$db = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysqli_select_db($db, "$databasename") or die ("no database"); 
mysqli_query($db, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'");

function mysqli_result($db,$row=0,$col=0){ 
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($db); 
    if ($numrows && $row <= ($numrows-1) && $row >=0){
        mysqli_data_seek($db,$row);
        $resrow = (is_numeric($col)) ? mysqli_fetch_row($db) : mysqli_fetch_assoc($db);
        if (isset($resrow[$col])){
            return $resrow[$col];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$word = "";

var_dump($_GET);    
var_dump(isset($word));

if($word)
    {       
        $getWord=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT word,definition FROM mdglossary WHERE word LIKE '$word' ORDER BY word");
    }
    else {....}

if($getWordArray=mysqli_fetch_array($getWord, MYSQLI_BOTH))
    {
    do
        {
        echo "....";
        }
    while($getWordArray=mysqli_fetch_array($getWord));
    }
else {....}
```

I try to find solution "hundret" times by Internet and this page, but I just can't understand what happened and why it doesn't work at all.

Comment: your query is failing... Looks like you actually want an `ALTER TABLE ` type query.

Comment: Right above `$getWord=mysqli_query...` try adding `echo $word;` to see if the variable is being set.

Comment: Just a note but this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Also I feel like you need to clear this up "In form i send a variable to address like page.php?word=xxx in page.php it should get $word from table.word with table.definition" because if you're wanting to get it from the request it should just be $_GET['word']

Comment: What does `var_dump($getWord);` show?

Comment: @Jacey when I use $word = $_GET['word'];  - when echo works. but still doesn't work

Comment: @Marcin, I don't see `$word = $_GET['word']` in your code after `$word=''`, so your query result will be empty.

Comment: I found where is problem. There was wrong (old) syntax for $getWord=mysqli_query in other part of page  - like $getWord=mysqli_query("...", $db) - comming form old $getWord=mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

You have set word to equal nothing.

```
$word = "";
```

then your sql will look like this

```
SELECT word,definition FROM mdglossary WHERE word LIKE '' ORDER BY word
```

So your looking for a word column with nothing in it. Is that your intention?

Comment: no - i try just to set variable to full this with xxx from address - without this also doesn't work

Comment: huh? you are setting word to nothing right in your code, it wont matter what you use for get as you have set it to '' in your code, it will override the get